# Templated robot test case doesn't always run Setup and Teardown keywords

Tags: python, robotframework

I expect the Test Setup and Test Teardown keywords to run for every execution of a templated test but that does not seem to be the case.  Here's a boiled-down version of my test suite that demonstrates what I'm talking about.  I run it like `pybot template-problem.txt`.  Notice that the resulting log file shows that my `Test Case Setup` and `Test Case Teardown` keywords were each run only one time.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup        Test Case Setup
Test Teardown     Test Case Teardown

*** Test Cases ***
Look for All Possible Outputs from the System Under Test
    [Template]    Look for Specific Output
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E
    F
    G
    H
    I
    J
    K
    L
    M
    N
    O
    P
    Q
    R
    S
    T
    U
    V
    W
    X
    Y
    Z

*** Keywords ***
Test Case Setup
    Comment    Setting up before the test case runs

Test Case Teardown
    Comment    Cleaning up after the test case finishes

Look For Specific Output
    [Arguments]    ${output}
    Comment    Pretending to look for a specific output...
    Log    ${output}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Robot Framework documentation on test templates](https://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.1#test-templates):

> Whereas the body of the normal test case is constructed from keywords
>   and their possible arguments, test cases with template define only the
>   arguments for the template keyword.

So, using templates is just a way to transform your testcase into:

```
Look for All Possible Outputs from the System Under Test
    Look for Specific Output    A
    Look for Specific Output    B
    Look for Specific Output    C
    ...
```

i.e. it's still just one test case calling the same keyword many times in a row with different arguments.

Comment: Ah.  So it's the template for the body of a test, not a way to generate full-blown test cases from a template.  Thank you!